# how to resume a coroutine in lua?

Tags: lua

I was try to use coroutine in lua, I tried the code below, repl.it here https://repl.it/repls/WordyWonderfulVisitor and it does not print the list content in the loop.

```
local list = {1,2,3};

local function iter()
  for i, v in ipairs(list) do
    print(i, v)
    coroutine.yield();
  end
end

local co = coroutine.create(iter);
coroutine.resume(co);
coroutine.resume(co);
-- iter();
```

what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Because you yield when you resume the coroutine.So to learn the pair function of yield and resume will is helpful for you.

Comment: @上山老人 but the print is before yield

Comment: the first resume(co), do the print() first, and then print (1,1), and then yield() stop;the second resume(co), whill execute from the yield() and do the print() second, print (2, 2), and then yield() stop again.So if you want to print(3,3), you must resume(co) again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It prints `1 1` and `2 2` as expected and the results are the same in Lua 5.1-5.4 versions.

If you want to see one more result `3 3`, then you need to call resume one more time. You can also check the status of the coroutine by using `coroutine.status`, so after the first two executions you'll get `"suspended"` and after the execution is completed you'll get `"dead"`.

Comment: Could you tell me why it prints `thread: 0xb17730` twice, not `1 1` and `2 2` in repl.it ?

Comment: seems there is a bug in repl.it.  the code runs fine in https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo. anyway , thanks